# How do I check if my barcode scanner adheres to the USB HID POS Scanner specification?

Tags: c#, usb, barcode-scanner, hid

I am trying to use [Windows-Universal-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples) for a barcode scanner, however after building the solution, the program is unable to locate the barcode scanner. I read that the barcode scanner needs to adhere to the "**USB HID POS Scanner specification**" I am not really sure what that means and how to check for it. [This is the barcode scanner](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06ZYHPYMV) I am using. The scanner worked fine wired and bluetooth mode when I am scanning to a text box or Notepad, but I would like to catch the data received event programmatically.

According to the manual the scanner has the following interfaces: USB HID, USB Virtual Serial, SPP and single, continuous and automatic scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**USB HID POS Scanner specification** is described in this document: [HID Point of Sale Usage Tables](http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/pos1_02.pdf).

It is a specification that is not used so much, and the equipment that support is limited.

**Supported devices are listed here**: [Supported Point of Service Peripherals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-device-support).

It seems that the device you want to use is not listed.
However, if you can set the scanner to `SPP-SSI mode` of `Bluetooth`, there is a possibility that it can be used, so please try it.

If it does not work, please ask the scanner vendor whether there is a device driver according to this specification [Barcode scanner driver sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/pos/barcode-scanner-driver) or can create a device driver.

Answer (score 0):

We use Intermec scanners but yours should work the same (check your link, btw, it's broken). If you program the scanner to work in USB HID mode (HID POS mode for some scanners), it should enumerate itself to the host as a HID POS device by reporting a usage page of 0x8c, according to HID specs. If it's not doing that, you need to check your code, make sure it's not filtering by HID usage page.